# How can I run cucumber feature file in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, cucumber

I am working with Netbeans and want to run a feature cucumber file. I have created the runner but there is no option to run as a JUnit test. I am using Netbeans 7.3 and cucumber cetriolo - plugin for Netbeans.

Comment: Can you please post your test runner? Is this a maven project?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting up the `.feature` file using the plugin (instead of manually):

1. Right click on the project and create a new empty `.features` file
2. Then in the file tab (not the Projects tab) put all the other 2 files alongside the features file in `~/src/test`

Comment: This is not a right answer. I'm struggling with the exact problem of the OP, anyone figured it out yet?